# Some guidance needed concerning a suggested edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just reviewed an edit and rejected it because it looked wrong to me.
The edit suggested a modification with respect to indices in some formula.
https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/43644.
It was reviewed by two other people who accepted the edit.
I feel the original post was correct and that the edit introduced an error. Can someone confirm I am not making a mistake?
Assuming I don't, should I revert the edit?

I am new about the editing process. Some guidance would be welcome.

Comment: If you find a wrong edit, revert it. -- Besides, I think the suggested edits review queue is geared too much towards acceptance of edits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the specific case, I confirm the edit is not good, as the formula has incoherent indexing [and it is just not right, too] (and I rolled it back right away).

On the general matter:

- Edits concerning the mathematical substance of a post should only be undertaken with great care. When in doubt on a suggested edit, do *not* approve the edit. If you feel not competent on the matter "skip," if you feel competent "reject" (possibly with a custom reason explaining the concern.)
- If you notice such an edit. If you are confident the edit is not good "rollback" (possibly leaving a comment; you can @-notify *editors* of a post even though they are not suggested in the auto-complete.) If you are unclear about the merits of an edit, comment on it (notifying the editor).